# How to access object from parent in custom if helper?

Tags: javascript, backbone-views, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

The `../../Message.NotAvailable` in the ifequal helper doesn't seem to work but if i provide a string "Hello" to compare with type it works fine and comes inside the loop

```
{{#ifequal type ../../Message.NotAvailable}}
    <li id="{{id}}"><a href="#">{{../../../Message.NotAvailable}}</a> </li>
    {{/ifequal}}
```

**My helper:**

```
  Handlebars.registerHelper('ifequal', function(value1, value2, options) {
    if(value1 === value2) {
        return options.fn(this);
    }
    return options.inverse(this);
});
```

**EDIT:**

I have tried removing `../../` from the variable as well doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What is wrong with the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Message.NotAvailable` is in the parent template scope, use `../Message.NotAvailable`.

> The `../` path segment references the parent template scope, not one level up in the context.
>   [image]